# Many to many table queries

Tags: sql, join

I have a many to many index table, and I want to do an include/exclude type query on it.

fid is really a integer index, but here as letters for easier understanding.  Here's a sample table :

table t

```
eid | fid
----+----
1   | A
1   | B
1   | C
2   | B
2   | C
3   | A
3   | C
4   | A
4   | B
5   | B
```

Here are some sample queries I want.

1. What eids have fid B, and NOT A?  (Answer eid 2 and 5)
2. What eids have fid C, and NOT A?  (Answer eid 2)

I can't seem to figure out a query that will do this.

I've tried a self join like this:

```
select * 
from t as t1 
join t as t2 
where t1.eid=t2.eid 
  and t1.fid!=t2.fid 
  and t1.fid=B and t2.fid!=A
```

That won't work, because it will still return rows where eid=1 and fid=C.

Am I clear on what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of a query for 1 (2 works much the same)

```
select t1.eid
  from t t1
 where t1.fid  = 'B'
   and not exists
       (select 1
          from t t2
         where t2.eid = t1.eid
           and t2.fid  = 'A')
```

Answer (score 7):

Use [set subtraction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx)

> ```
> Select eid from t where fid = 'B' 
> EXCEPT
> select eid from t where fid = 'A'
> ```

Comment: Great tip; I've actually never used the EXCEPT syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a sub-select

select eid from t where fid = 'C' and eid not in (select eid from t where fid = 'A')

Answer (score 0):

[MySQL 5.0](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) supports the where exists/where not exists, as described by Nigel and Mike.

Answer (score 0):

Version with straight joins that may be faster than using EXISTS:

```
Select  t1.eid
From    #test t1
        left join (
            Select  eid
            From    #test t2 
            Where   fid = 'A'
            Group by eid
        ) t2 on t2.eid = t1.eid 
Where   t1.fid = 'B'
        and t2.eid is null
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to do this without using a subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.eid
FROM table1 AS t1
  LEFT JOIN table1 AS t2 ON (t1.eid = t2.eid AND t2.fid = 'A')
WHERE t2.eid IS NULL
  AND t1.fid = 'B';
```

To do your second example search, just change the value 'B' to 'C'.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the MINUS operator.  It works like UNION, except that it subtracts where UNION adds.  The previous answer with the word "EXCEPT" may be a different keyword for the same thing.

Here's an untested answer:

```
select eid 
from t
where fid = 'A'
minus
select eid
from t
where fid = 'B'
```